# Linq to sql left join and group by

Tags: linq-to-sql, group-by, left-join

I have 2 tables
table1

```
ID    Name
1     name1
2     name2
3     name3
4     name4
```

table2

```
ID   Description    Status
 1    desc1           1
 1    desc2           1
 2    desc3           1
 3    desc4           0
```

I need to get list of items {ID, Name} which are not in second table or are all stopped in second table. This items should be grouped.
in this example I should get 
{1, name1},
{2, name2},
{4, name4}.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should get what you want:

```
var result = from p in table1
               where table2.Any(x => x.ID == p.ID) == false
               || table2.Any(x => x.ID == p.ID && x.Status == 1)
               select p;
```